# How to create a blank page (external page) in Magento in code with a specific magento template applied to it

Tags: magento

Not sure on the best way to go around this and am looking for solutions. I have the requirement to create a blank page (that I will later add code to) with a specific theme as the design. I've created the custom theme at: /app/design/frontend/indigo/mytheme/ and need to know how to create a page lets call it /test.php that has the theme applied to it.

Code so far is this, but this only shows the default theme:

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default'); 
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//get the loaded head and header blocks and output
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
$footerBlock = $layout->getBlock('footer');

echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml();
?>
My content goes here
<?php
echo $footerBlock->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this was down voted? I thought it was a reasonable question that I could not find the answer to on SO.

Comment: perhaps not the cleanest solution but the question itself I think is very reasonable! wtf SO.. I was looking for the same thing here.. but I was hoping for some cleaner solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite basic, you just need to set the store ID:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(STORE_ID);
```

So the final code looks like this:

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('STORE_ID', 15);
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(STORE_ID);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default'); 
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php echo $layout->getBlock('head')->toHtml() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $layout->getBlock('after_body_start')->toHtml() ?>
<?php echo $layout->getBlock('global_notices')->toHtml() ?>
<?php echo $layout->getBlock('header')->toHtml() ?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container_12">
        <?php echo $layout->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml() ?>
        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
            <div class="grid_12 col-main">
                <?php echo $layout->getBlock('global_messages')->toHtml() ?>
                <?php echo $layout->getBlock('content')->toHtml() ?>
                My content goes here
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $layout->getBlock('footer')->toHtml() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are cleaner solutions you could take out of these: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154974/create-completely-empty-page-in-magento-1-9-2-4 depending on how close to core you want to be :)

**EDIT - A Clean complete solution:**

Create a new custom controller (https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html)

```
class Vendor_Module_LoremController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    /**
     * Get a shop now block for specific product
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        // Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()); // If you need to debug to see which layout handles are available
    }
}
```

In your themes local.xml ( /app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/layout/local.xml ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <vendor_module_lorem_index>
        <remove name="header" />
        <remove name="footer" />
    </vendor_module_lorem_index>
</layout>
```